# restrict access to a specific cluster node on MSSQL/AG 2016

Tags: sql-server

I am managing an instance running on mssql 2016 in high availability group (2 nodes)
one of the nodes is used for OLTP, while the second is used for user queries

Is it possible to allow access to a specific list of OS users (admin PDL) while deny others, to the OLTP node and yet allow them to login to the second node?

appreciate your assistance

thanks

Comment: You could control access to each node by disabling selected logins on the primary. But the common approach would be to use read-only routing and specify ReadOnlyIntent in the connection string to automatically direct read-only traffic to the secondary. That way, you have HA if the secondary becomes unavailable or after a role switch.

Comment: Thanks Dan.  But in my case it doesnt help. i need to kick out users which are not part of a certain AD group when they try to connect. need to cover both discipline and mistakes...

Comment: Maybe some kind of login event?

Comment: You might be able to use a login trigger that examines role membership using `IS_MEMBER()`, check whether the current node is the primary, and if the secondary is available (to allow connections if only the primary is available for queries). This assumes all connections are via the listener.